# Are "Thank You for Unsubscribing to our Newsletter" emails necessary?

Tags: email, notification, confirmation, subscription

I am about to disable the "Send a Thank You for Unsubscribing to our Newsletter" message for some of our clients as I think it's superfluous and unnecessary.

My suggestion was to have an Unsubscribe link that links to a "Thank You for Unsubscribing" message on their website and to leave it at that.

What is the best practice here?

Comment: Many sites I unsubscribed from their lists presented me with a screen going "we're sorry to see you go". The more constructive websites showed me how I can re-subscribe easily in the future, in case I change my mind.

Answer (score 11):

**Your approach makes sense** as it fulfils two important functions:

- Confirm the client's action (by showing a message on the web page)
- Carry out the client's request (by not sending any more email, including confirmation)

A confirmation email would be superfluous, unnecessary and redundant since you've already confirmed the request on the web page.

Comment: those mails make my eyes pop out. it's an insult!

Comment: Sam K points out that this only holds if you know that the client knows about the request. If you allow unauthenticated requests then you will indeed need to send an email to the (ex-)subscriber, offering the option to cancel the unsubscription. There are a few more wrinkles to consider in this case too.

Answer (score 7):

The only occasion I can think of where such a message is useful is if it's not actually the owner of the address who performs the unsubscribe. If someone else unsubscribes my address from a service, without that confirmation message I'd be none the wiser.

For the vast majority of mailing lists, this is hardly the end of the world and it's probably a very, very minor consideration overall but still something worth thinking about, perhaps.

It would also serve as a proof that the unsubscribe request had been received and processed should a query ever arise.

This may be a classic case of over-analysing a very small thing, but they're just some points that came to mind.